# Why does the `describe` function display floats using scientific notation?

Tags: python, pandas

Data in a .csv file looks like this:

[image]

But when I am using function `describe` it shows me numbers in scientific notation?

How can I format them within `describe` function?

[image]

Comment: Would `pd.set_option('float_format',lambda x: "%.6f" % x)` work? https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6842

Comment: Thanks. Could you post an answer so I'll accept it? Thank you

Comment: Great! posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following as mentioned in similar [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6842):

```
pd.set_option('float_format',lambda x: "%.6f" % x)
```

From the document:

```
display.float_format : callable
    The callable should accept a floating point number and return
    a string with the desired format of the number. This is used
    in some places like SeriesFormatter.
    See formats.format.EngFormatter for an example.
    [default: None] [currently: None]
```